# How to find a sub-string from a string in a variable using groovy

Tags: string, if-statement, groovy, substring

[Screenshot of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMGgy.png)
I have a variable **err** = "http code 401"

now I want to do a if condition by reading that variable and if it finds 401 it should echo a message.

Something like,

```
if (${err}.contains('401'))
{
    println "Unauthorized"
}
```

The above works in java, how to implement the same in groovy.

Help Appreciated!

**PS: Edited the actual post after trying the inputs from comments

Answer (score 0):

Construct like `${err}` can be used e.g. in a string, in **double** quotes,
to interpolate a variable, i.e. to create a string variable **containing**
some other variable and also other content.

Here use just `if (err.contains('401')) {...`

Note: In your example you missed one `)`.

Comment: and also replace the echo with a `println "Unauthorized"` as `echo` is not a valid groovy statement.

Comment: @Valdi_Bo No, I tried the above code but it didn't work. The variable is not loading if specified as if (err.contains('401')) {...} So, because of that "if condition" is not executing at all but if i echo ${err} its loading properly. Not sure how to pass ${err} inside "if condition" since its throwing an error

Comment: You still write about using "echo", which is not supported in Groovy. Are using another language, e.g. bash?

Comment: I am using try and catch method in groovy and when I catch the error its not a string. 
I need to convert it to string 

if (err.toString().contains('401')) {..} This worked

Thanks all!